# Why was Bond not given advanced weapons?

Tags: james-bond, skyfall

Since I was a kid, I used to watch 007 just to see what new weapon he will be using. I bought two PS2 games just to use these cool weapons and drive the BMW which can fire rockets! Or to use the watch and break the glass.

I didn't watch 007 because I like the actors, every new Bond movie has different cast, I didn't watch it because I loved the plot or because I want to see a story, we all know how bond movie ends: he falls in love with a blonde girl, who is a bad girl, the good girl is black, the blonde dies, Bond kills the bad guy and fall in love with the good girl.

I watched 007 because I wanted to see incredible weapons never seen before and we used to talk about it for months!

*Skyfall* on the other hand is good, however they used a fake Q and fake weapons, they killed the blonde girl too early and made her a hopeless girl. The black girl didn't do anything in the movie beside shooting Bond in the first scene.

There's something wrong! Who will watch *Iron Man* if he doesn't have that fancy suit and a billion different weapon? Same story with Bond, the story is good, but it seems more like a Jason Bourne movie, not James Bond (Jason does what James does without having the cool weapons).

So why didn't the director give Bond his cool guns and car? Is it a lack of creativity or what? And can we expect to see the cool guns in the next Bond? or is the future of the franchise going to be about a man who kills using traditional - old weapons?

Comment: While this is an interresting question that might provoke insightful answers, it definitely has to be "de-subjectified" *a lot*. Well, in fact it even seems to be a duplicate if considering all of the *Craig*-movies (which is reasonable as this lack of *"cool weapons"* started much earlier with *Casino Royale* already).

Comment: Early Bond films (the best ones, IMHO) did not really have much in the way of gadgetry. I think the only gadget in Dr. No was the geiger counter. Furthermore, in Dr. No, Honey Ryder is a blonde good girl while Sylvia Trench and Miss Taro are brunette bad girls.